# How to free memory allocated with LoadGFX in C++?

Tags: c++, free

I wrote a simple asteroids game in C++ using Visual Studio. It works fine but I was wondering whether before exiting the game it would be better to free the memory allocated for the some images and sounds. I load the assets in the init function as shown below.

```
//Define array of textures for intro screen message "ASTEROIDS"
void*   g_texturesIntro[] = 
{
    "gfx/alet.png",
    "gfx/slet.png",
    "gfx/tlet.png",
    "gfx/elet.png",
    "gfx/rlet.png",
    "gfx/olet.png",
    "gfx/ilet.png",
    "gfx/dlet.png",
    "gfx/slet.png"
};


//Function to initialize game
void Init()
{
    //Load assets
    //Intro screen textures
    int const numNTexturesIntro = sizeof(g_texturesIntro) / sizeof(g_texturesIntro[0]);
    for (int k = 0; k < numNTexturesIntro; k++)
    {
        g_texturesIntro[k] = LoadGFX((char*)g_texturesIntro[k]);
    }
}
```

I tried adding the code below to free the memory occupied but the game crashes when I exit it.

```
//Function to shutdown game
void Shutdown()
{
    //Free assets
    //Intro screen textures
    int const numNTexturesIntro = sizeof(g_texturesIntro) / sizeof(g_texturesIntro[0]);
    for (int k = 0; k < numNTexturesIntro; k++)
    {
        free(g_texturesIntro[k]);
    }
    free(g_texturesIntro);
}
```

Do you have to free up memory allocated with LoadGFX, and if so how do I properly do it?

Comment: Is `g_texturesIntro` a pointer? Does it point to memory you allocated with `malloc`? If you answered no to any of those questions, then you should not pass it to `free`. You should only call `free` passing pointers that was returned by `malloc` (or null pointers).

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to overwrite the contents of `g_texturesIntro`? That assignment in the loop in `Init` will make you lose the original content. Also, if `g_texturesIntro` is a pointer, your "trick" to get the number of elements will not work.

Comment: What is LoadGFX to start with?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've added the code that initializes the array `g_texturesIntro`, so no it was not allocated with `malloc`. Therefore no need to call `free` on it right?

Comment: @Yiannis It's also not a pointer; it's an array. That's a double "no" to `free`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `LoadGFX` is a library function that creates a texture from an image file

Comment: @Yiannis From what library?

Comment: Then I assume the library documentation also explains how to free the resources? We can't guess without knowing what a random library does.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I can't seem to find any documentation on the function online, I tried looking before posting the question but no luck